# Can't click on input, textarea and button of form

Tags: css, html, forms

I can't click on elements of my form (textarea, input and button). I checked if there is any overlapping element by the Chrome tool, but don't find anything.

The address is: http://danielgroppo.com/chamonix/public_html/contato

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit in the relevant code. Questions with only links are not considered to be of good quality.

Comment: `#content` `z-index` is -1. Remove it and it will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you use

```
z-index: -1;
```

on `#content`. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe the Twitter Bootstrap makes a transparent div overlaying the page.

Comment: Thanks this helped me debug the issue deep within the plugin BlockUI JS library.
Likely cause is creating any amount of z-index: xxx on top of the existing one.
Not neccessarily has it be z-index: -1